# How do we make RDF schema compatible with OWL?

Tags: owl, rdfs

I have been trying to research making rdf schema compatible with web ontology language but I am still new and still getting mixed up. any help with this is highly appreciated.
I need to know if there is anything I should remove or omit from rdfs to make it compatible with the owl.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, almost every RDFS class expression and property hierarchy are valid in OWL.

Exceptions are containers and uses of rdfs:Resource and rdf:Property.

Edit:
From the [OWL 2 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/#Semantics):

> 2.3 Semantics
>
> The OWL 2 Structural Specification document defines the abstract structure of OWL 2 ontologies, but it does not define their meaning. The Direct Semantics [OWL 2 Direct Semantics] and the RDF-Based Semantics [OWL 2 RDF-Based Semantics] provide two alternative ways of assigning meaning to OWL 2 ontologies, with a correspondence theorem providing a link between the two. These two semantics are used by reasoners and other tools, e.g., to answer class consistency, subsumption and instance retrieval queries.

So you need to be aware first of what semantics is appropriate for your application. RDF semantics is fully included in `OWL 2 FULL`, so if you /need/ all RDF constructs, you'll have to deal with OWL 2 FULL, which means any reasoners you can use will be incomplete.

The most common situation, however, is to need only OWL 2 DL or a simpler profile; this poses restrictions on the RDF constructs used.

As mentioned before, subclass axioms in RDFS are compatible with OWL; subproperty axioms as well. Restrictions are: all classes and properties need to be declared; properties can be declared as object, data or annotation properties, but cannot have two types.

For an RDF centric view, see this blog post:  http://www.epimorphics.com/web/wiki/owl-2-rdf-vocabularies

Comment: Couple of nitpicks: first of all, lists and collections are the same thing in RDF (or in OWL - so I'm not sure why you'd say they'd be invalid there) - did you mean _containers_ rather than collections? Second: it's `rdfs:Resource`.

Comment: so nothing to remove from rdfs?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Yes you're right. My bad for typing the reply on my phone.

Comment: can you please give me more details, as I am new to this